# What's the correct syntax for overriding an interface member function with a visibility modifier?

Tags: kotlin

Neither of the two pages, the one on [Interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html), nor the one on [Visibility Modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) provides an example of the syntax I am after, so I ask.

I have an interface like so:

```
package bookyard.contracts;

public interface IAuthenticationManager<T> {
    fun authenticateUser(userName: String, password : String,
                            appId: String, appSecret : String) : OperationResult<T>;
}
```

And I am writing an implementation for it but neither of the three below listed syntaxes work. Each time, the compiler reports the following error:

> 1. 'authenticateUser' overrides nothing
> 2. Class 'DatabaseAuthenticationManager' must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract fun authenticateUser(userName: String, password: String, appId: String, appSecret: String): OperationResult defined in bookyard.contracts.IAuthenticationManager

```
package bookyard.server.util

import bookyard.contracts.IAuthenticationManager;

public class DatabaseAuthenticationManager :  IAuthenticationManager<User> {

    /* override public fun authenticateUser(userName : String?,
                                password : String?,
                                appId : String?,
                                appSecret : String?) : OperationResult<User> {
    }

    public override fun authenticateUser(userName : String?,
                                password : String?,
                                appId : String?,
                                appSecret : String?) : OperationResult<User> {
    }

    public fun authenticateUser(userName : String?,
                                password : String?,
                                appId : String?,
                                appSecret : String?) : OperationResult<User> {
    } */
}
```

Comment: You're using `String?` instead of `String` as the data type for a lot of the parameters. They aren't interchangeable. You can make your interface use nullable Strings and it won't complain about the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using nullable Strings when attempting to implement the interface.

*From [Kotlin's documentation about null-safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)...*

> In Kotlin, the type system distinguishes between references that can hold null (nullable references) and those that can not (non-null references).

`String?` (nullable String) and `String` are considered to be **different types** by Kotlin. Therefore the compiler thinks that you haven't implemented the method.

#### Your options...

You have 2 options:

1. **Update your interface** to use nullable parameters (by adding `?` to the end of each type).
2. **Update your implementation** to use non-nullable parameters (`String`).

I think option 2 is slightly cleaner since it **won't break** any other existing implementations of the interface.

#### Example (for option 2):

*The interface stays unchanged.*

*Here's the new implementation...*

```
package bookyard.server.util

import bookyard.contracts.IAuthenticationManager

class DatabaseAuthenticationManager : IAuthenticationManager<User> {

    override fun authenticateUser(userName : String,
                                  password : String,
                                  appId : String,
                                  appSecret : String) : OperationResult<User> {
        // Your implementation...
    }
}
```

You can see that all I've done is change each parameter from `String?` to `String`.

#### Notes:

- Classes/fields/interfaces are **public by default**, the `public` keyword is unnecessary.
- Kotlin has **semi-colon inference** so you don't need to add semi-colons yourself. There are *rare* cases where you will actually *need* to, but the compiler will warn you in advance.

Comment: Thank you. Well spotted. That was an oversight on my part.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 To be fair, it took me a while to spot it too. Easy mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Every overridden method needs to conform to the interface declared parameter nullability. In other words the correct way to implement the interface would be:

```
class DatabaseAuthenticationManager :  IAuthenticationManager<User> {
    override fun authenticateUser(userName: String, password: String, appId: String, appSecret: String): OperationResult<User> {
        ...
    }
}
```